# Jetpack Compose: Keyboard covers the TextField in dialog

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In short: using Jetpack Compose, the keyboard overlaps the TextField when it is opened in an AlertDialog.
I've tried everything I've found:

- added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`
- set `decorFitsSystemWindows = false` on the `DialogProperties`
- called `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` for the dialog's `window`
- called `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` in the Activity's `onCreate()` method
- used this `ImeState` approach from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgoJfl_Oc5E
- used the `BringIntoViewRequester`:

  ```
  modifier
      .onFocusEvent {
          if (it.isFocused) {
              coroutineScope.launch {
                  delay(200)
                  bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
              }
          }
      }
      .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
  ```

I've created a GitHub repository with a demo project: [Demo project - TextField covered by keyboard](https://github.com/FRbrt/Compose-Keyboard-Covers-TextField-Demo/tree/main/KeyboardHidesTextField/app/src/main/java/edu/keyboardhidestextfield)

**Can you help me to understand what am I missing?
I'm completely out of ideas.**

Screenshots:
[image: Dialog with TextField]
[image: TextField covered by the keyboard]

## UPDATE - SOLVED

Based on the answer of @Shubham Thorat, I used `adjustPan` in the following way:

- AndroidManifest.xml: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`
- in the `LaunchedEffect(imeState.value)`:

  ```
  WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(wnd, false)
  wnd.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
  ```

Comment: Did you try using ```imePadding()``` to you ```TextField``` because it will add keyboard spacing below the ```TextField```

Comment: yup, it's the same

Comment: How did you get window (wnd) in Compose?

Comment: Like this: https://github.com/FRbrt/Compose-Keyboard-Covers-TextField-Demo/blob/main/KeyboardHidesTextField/app/src/main/java/edu/keyboardhidestextfield/DialogWithTextFieldContent.kt#L28-L29


val windowProvider = LocalView.current.parent as? DialogWindowProvider
val window = windowProvider?.window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this one:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: @Robert: Please don’t edit questions to include solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your column:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        //add this
        .imePadding()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState),
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(boxHeight)
            .background(LightYellow)
    ) {

    }

    CustomTextField(textFieldValueState = textFieldValueState)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried setting imePadding(), unfortunately it solve it.

Comment: Ok you should set it at the Column

Comment: I've accepted an answer, setting to "adjustPan" both for the dialog's window and manifest solved it.

Comment: Works for me, I used scrollable instead of verticalScroll